# Create Pie Chart based on 2 number fields in PowerApps

Tags: charts, powerapps-modeldriven

I have a table called Event in PowerApps.
I have a whole number column called Capacity, which holds the maximum number of attendees.
I have a rollup column called Attendees, which counts the number of EventAttendee records in the related table.

I'd like to have a Pie Chart on the main form which shows the number of attendees out of the capacity (so if there is a capacity of 20 and currently 15 attendees, shows 75%).
From within the table, I select Data Experiences --> Charts and create a new chart. I select Pie Chart.

But from there, I'm a bit stumped. I don't know which field to add to which "bit" of the pie chart in order to show what I want.
Any advice gratefully received.